# Why is my Apache Ignite persistent store remaining locked?

Tags: java, ignite

I have an application that uses Apache Ignite as a single node cluster.  That is, Ignite is started and stopped by the application and its lifecycle matches the application.

The Ignite caches have both persistent storage and read-through enabled.  So,

1. First call to cache.get() --> nothing in cache, reads through via `CacheAdapter` to backing store (an Oracle database) and loads the entry into the cache.
2. Subsequent call to cache.get() -> returns from cache
3. Application bounces, the call cache.get()  --> returns from cache (from persistent store).  **Key point is that it does *not* read through to the backing store after an application bounce!**

All this seems to be working wonderfully.  Here is my problem: sometimes (fairly often) when the application is bounced or redeployed, the persistent store `data` directory remains locked as far as Apache Ignite is concerned.  As a result, Ignite silently creates a new, empty persistent store, which defeats the whole purpose of persistent storage.

Our data directory currently looks like this:

```
-sh-4.2$ pwd
/myapp/oracle/user_projects/domains/myapp_inst/igniteCache/myserver/data
-sh-4.2$ ls -ltr
total 48
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Jan  9 16:25 node00-7c02d9ab-7ef3-4d01-8ebd-d1184fa281a2
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Jan  9 17:28 node01-06a5d059-1b62-4ac2-84bf-5325deac8138
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb  4 15:39 node02-ba720d52-570a-448c-9109-75687ee664e7
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb  5 12:16 node03-d2c521aa-e0ee-471b-ad16-08af382a1e3d
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb  6 17:44 node04-505e754e-a3d3-48b1-a759-d5ec8867dc96
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb  6 18:23 node05-ec0f89e3-bfe5-4bb6-87da-302951439f66
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb 13 15:41 node06-5b9dc33a-42f6-4f1c-8d57-14d5ddb30dc5
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb 13 15:43 node07-47aacde5-2598-4a85-9383-761e569bb1d1
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb 13 15:47 node08-0374a51d-4b90-4e5a-9465-adabc900ea0b
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb 13 15:52 node09-610c69c6-35e0-4d74-90db-6be09bb77659
-rw-r-----.  1 mygroup mygroup   41 Feb 13 17:00 lock
drwxr-x---. 10 mygroup mygroup 4096 Feb 13 17:00 node10-f115d95b-7b76-41e0-bd32-966030331c9c
```

There should only be one "nodeXX..." directory above.

**Questions**

1. Is there anything I can do my application to ensure that, whatever the failure, the persistent store locks are released?
2. Is there anything I can do on application startup to tell Ignite to break or delete the lock and not create a new, empty store every time?
3. Is there anything I can do in my application to tell Ignite that this persistent store is local to the node and that, therefore, locks aren't necessary?

Really, anything I can do to get around this behavior would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set Ignite ConsistentId:
igniteCfg.setConsistentId("My_Node_Id" + id);
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-persistence-path-management

in this case, ignite will try to acquire file lock and wait for 10 seconds, if it fails to acquire it, it won't create a new folder, but fail with an exception.